# how to use const value in styled component

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, styled-components

I want to pass styled component to the variable and then use that variable in the render part

I am not sure how to use that, The purpose for passing through variable is for condition

Sample.styled.tsx

```
import styled from 'styled-components'

export const sampleCoder = styled.div`
border: none;
margin: 0 15px 0 0;
padding: 0 16px 0 0;

export const sampleCoder1 = styled.div`
border: 1px solid black;
margin: 0 15px 0 0;
padding: 0 16px 0 0;
```

sampleRow.tsx

```
import React from 'react'
import { sampleCoder } from './Sample.styled'

intrerface someprops{
 text: boolean
}

export const CardRowLabelValue = {someprops} => {
let SampleStyle = '<sampleCoder> '
SampleStyle += props.text? ' <sampleCoder1>' : ''

return (
<SampleStyle>
 <someOtherStyledComponent>{text} </someOtherStyledComponent>
</SampleStyle>
)
```

Return value should be variable value, How to get variable value in the return statement
is it possible ?

Comment: What's your goal? Looking at your code if props.text, you end up with `<sampleCoder><sampleCoder1>` which is wrong. Are you trying to concatenate styles in sampleCoder1 to sampleCoder if props.text is defined?

Comment: @kimobrian254 yes i want to concatenate this 2 if i inspect element  it should show ex (.sampleCode1.sampleCode,) if text is false it should show me only (.sampleCode)

Comment: Ok. There's a different way of doing it. First, in your implementation, props.text will always be undefined since this `<SampleStyle>{text}<SampleStyle>` does pass in text as props. It's a child. Let me make a quick sample to achieve this.

Comment: Sure Thanks @kimobrian254

Comment: @kimobrian254 i  have done small change on the return part not to worry about prop text

Comment: I added a Codesandbox snippet, let me know if that solves your issue.

Comment: Hi Have done small change

Comment: I still think the code I posted gives what you need since you need that prop to control the style.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226294/discussion-between-user13465472-and-kimobrian254).

Answer (score 1):

I made a [Codesandbox snippet and here's the link](https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-cerf-t08n5?file=/src/App.js)

The css helper function generates the specific css and returns it as a template literal.
I'll also add the code here just in case. The idea is to merge the styles if props.text is defined. Also watch where I put `${(props) => (props.text ? sampleCoder : "")};`. Putting this line before `border: none` will override the border styles.

```
import React from "react";
import styled, { css } from "styled-components";

export const sampleCoder = css`
  border: none;
  margin: 0 15px 0 0;
  padding: 0 16px 0 0;
`;

export const SampleCoder = styled.div`
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0 15px 0 0;
  padding: 0 16px 0 0;
  ${(props) => (props.text ? sampleCoder : "")};
`;

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <SampleCoder text={"Text props"}>Text props provided</SampleCoder>
      <SampleCoder>No text prop, just children</SampleCoder>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: sampleCoder  is not adding in SampleCoder
${(props) => (props.text ? sampleCoder : "")} seems like it is not concating